# Javascript - Comparar campo de input com field de mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Alguém me pode indicar informação sobre isto? Estou tentando aprender ou então demonstração com explicação

O que quero fazer é ter  input em html e ir buscar o valor desse input verificar se ele existe numa determinada coleção e se existir faz algo se não faz algo!

Obrigado a quem ajudar!

Sou iniciante na matéria

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que você esteja usando mongoose e express, no seu controller você pode fazer:

```
function findOneInput(req, res) {
   Model.findOne({ field: req.query.input }, function (error, input) {
      // Trata erro
      if(error) {
         console.error(error)
         res.status(500).msg({ msg: 'Um erro ocorreu' })
      }
      // Manda o documento para o usuario
      res.json(input)     
   })
}
```

Já na view, você precisaria fazer uma requisição à sua API, passando o input na query. O URI ficaria: `example.com/api/nome-da-rota?input=valor-do-usuario`. A API iria te retornar `null` se o documento não existir no DB e te voltaria o documento se ele existir. Daí basta fazer um if.

P.S.: Isso aí tá bem geral, é uma suposição de acordo com o que você publicou. Pode ser que outros ajustes tenham que ser feitos, em relação a segurança, performance e até mesmo a forma como você ajustou seus dados.

Comment: Amigo penso que vou precisar uma explicação mais detalhada o que quero é comparar o que o utilizador inserir num input e quero verificar se ele existe na base de dados mongo entende? Penso que me expliquei mal vou reformular no post

Comment: É exatamente isso que o código está fazendo. Você recebe essa informação do usuário em um arquivo HTML, e faz uma requisição na sua API para verificar se existe um campo com esse dado